# Boundedness of an implicit function

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus

I have a function $h(u) : \mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ in an implicit form:
$$
A(h, u) = 0. 
$$
What conditions could we put on $A$ to guarantee that $h$ is bounded? And if we have an explicit functional $F$, what would be the conditions to guarantee that $F(h(u))$ is bounded as a function of $u$?

Comment: Do you know anything about $A$? Why can it not be the constant $0$ function?

Comment: @Clayton, $A$ will be basically given explicitly, once I plug in the assumptions, however it will not have an explicit solution for $h$. I would like to find some conditions on $A$ that guarantees boundedness of $h$ and/or $F(h)$, so that I can fiddle with the assumptions.

Comment: Ah, so maybe your question can better be worded something like: What conditions can we put on $A$ to guarantee that $h$ is bounded? Or have I misinterpreted your comment?

Comment: @Clayton, fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following are evidently equivalent:

1. $\|h(u)\|\le M$ for all $u\in \mathbb R^N$
2. $A(h,u)\ne 0$ whenever $\|h\|>M$

Since the set $\{h\in \mathbb R^N : \|h\|>M\}$ is connected when $N>1$, condition 2 means that either

- (2a) $A(h,u)> 0$ whenever $\|h\|>M$, or
- (2b) $A(h,u)< 0$ whenever $\|h\|>M$.

Given explicit $A$, it is usually not difficult to check that  (2a), (2b) hold or fail.

For the second question: $F\circ h$ is bounded if and only if $F$ is bounded on the range of $h$. So, if $\|h(u)\|\le M$ for all $u$  (as above), then you only need $F$ to be bounded on the closed ball of radius $M$. In particular, the continuity of $F$ will be enough to conclude that $F\circ h$ is bounded in this case.